# Deriving the Area of a Circle with an Integral in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, circles, area

I was wondering how we can derive the area of a circle with radius $r$ by taking an integral over $x$ in the coordinate plane. If we graph a quarter-circle, it would just be on the first quadrant, and would be the integrable function:$$y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$Integrating this from $x=0$ to $x=r$ should give us one-fourth of the area of a circle with radius $r$, or ${{\pi}r^2}/{4}$. So, we get:$$\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx$$I know this can be integrated with trigonometric substitution, but if we use the inverse power rule (with the power being $1/2$), we get:$$[{(-{1/(3x)})(r^2-x^2)^{3/2}}]^r_0$$But, evaluating the bounds, we get $0$ for the first term, and $-r^3/0$ for the second term, and that’s a problem. This is where I am stuck. Could someone please explain my mistake or the next step?

Comment: You can’t divide by $x$ when applying the inverse power rule because it’s not constant.

Comment: If you take the derivative of your antiderivative, do you get the integrand back?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I now realize my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matthew pointed out, there is a misapplication of the inverse power rule when integrating

$$I=\int\mathrm dx\,\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$

However, if you truly want to avoid trigonometric substitution when evaluating this integral and want to remain strictly in Cartesian coordinates, here is an alternative that may or may not be what you're looking for.

First, rewriting the square root as shown below, we can rewrite the indefinite integral $I$ as

$$\begin{align*}I & =\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {R^2-x^2}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\\ & =R^2\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\color{brown}{-\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}}\end{align*}$$

Next, using integration by parts on $I$ with $u=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and $v=x$, then

$$I=x\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\color{brown}{+\int\mathrm dx\,\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}}$$

Adding the two different expressions for $I$, and observing that the brown expressions cancel each other out, then we're just left with a simplified integral

$$\begin{align*}I & =\frac 12x\sqrt{R^2-x^2}+\frac 12 R^2\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\\ & =\frac 12x\sqrt{R^2-x^2}+\frac 12 R^2\arcsin\left(\frac xR\right)+C\end{align*}$$

Imposing the limits from $x=0$ to $x=R$, then the expression becomes

$$\int\limits_0^R\mathrm dx\,\sqrt{R^2-x^2}=\frac 12 R^2\arcsin1\color{blue}{=\frac {\pi}4 R^2}$$

Which is indeed the area of a quarter circle!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the assumption that
$$
   \color{red}{\int \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx = -\frac{1}{3x}(r^2-x^2)^{3/2}+C}
$$
This isn't true because differentiating the right-hand side would give one extra term by the product rule:
$$
    \frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{1}{3x}(r^2-x^2)^{3/2}\right)
    = \sqrt{r^2-x^2} + \frac{1}{3x^2}(r^2-x^2)^{3/2}
$$
[Read more on Sympy Gamma](https://gamma.sympy.org/input/?i=diff%28%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2F%28-3*x%29%2Cx%29).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!